# R: How to search a character string using target and replacement words stored in a separate dataframe?

Tags: r, gsub

Start with an input character string like this:
`goats <- c("he gets her goat. they get her dog. i get my elephant.")`

My goal is to gsub a list of search and replacement terms from a separate dataframe applied to the original chr string object (goats). Here is a very simplified example of what such a dataframe will look like.

[image]

The problem with my regex syntax is that it stops after the first row of the target list is applied to the text object. I would like to continue to loop through the target list until all terms have been exhausted.  I tried:

```
newgoat <- character()
for (row in 1:seq_along(targlist$target)) {
  newgoat <- gsub(targlist$target, targlist$replacement, goats)
}
```

My output was:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in the `for` loop -

- `1:seq_along(targlist$target)` is incorrect. `seq_along(targlist$target)` already gives you the index to iterate over.
- You should subset `targlist$target` and `targlist$replacement` in the loop with the row index i.e `i`.
- In the loop `goats` is not changing at all, you should apply `gsub` on `newgoat` instead.

```
targlist <- data.frame(target = c('goat', 'dog', 'elephant'), 
                       replacement = c('banana', 'apple', 'pear'))

newgoat <- goats
for (i in seq_along(targlist$target)) {
  newgoat <- gsub(targlist$target[i], targlist$replacement[i], newgoat)
} 

newgoat
#[1] "he gets her banana. they get her apple. i get my pear."
```

---

There is also a non-loop version with `str_replace_all` -

```
stringr::str_replace_all(goats, setNames(targlist$replacement, targlist$target))

#[1] "he gets her banana. they get her apple. i get my pear."
```